# cakephp unit testing failed asserting that response has header 'Location'

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to test a cakephp add method which in UsersController, I have written below action in UsersController

```
public function testAdd(): void
{
        $this->enableCsrfToken();
        $this->enableSecurityToken();
        
        $user = ['username'=>'jone','email'=>'pitocms@yahoo.com', 'password'=>'123'];
        $this->post('users/add',$user);
        $this->assertRedirect('/users');
        $count = $this->Users->find('all')->where($user)->count();
        $this->assertEquals(1,$count);
 }
```

After run this test case I am getting below error

```
Time: 00:00.133, Memory: 14.00 MB

There was 1 failure:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\UsersControllerTest::testAdd
Failed asserting that response has header 'Location'.

/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake4/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/IntegrationTestTrait.php:833
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cake4/tests/TestCase/Controller/UsersControllerTest.php:89
```

How I will solve this problem ?

After remove `$this->assertRedirect('/users');` this script is working fine. Here How I will test action redirection is okay ?

Note : Here I am running cakephp application using cake server , by below command

```
bin/cake server
```

Location of `/users` is `http://localhost:8765/users`

Comment: Why would you assume that `assertRedirect()` is wrong? Wouldn't the more logical conclusion to that error be that there is possibly something wrong in your app/code that causes the header to not be present? Do some debugging, maybe start with inspecting the response in your test case, eg `debug($this->_response);`.

Comment: @ndm after remove assertRedirect() , my script is working fine. That's why I thought it's may be a cause for assertRedirect().

Comment: @ndm After debug I got actual cause , That was database default value set error in mysql. Because I haven't sent created in post data. Thank you for your help.